# How do I make the Minecarts active?

Tags: stardew-valley

The minecarts are all broken. Seems like they are pretty useful for fast traveling between some places around the city, farm and mines.

How do I make these work?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Once you complete the Boiler Room bundle, the minecarts will be repaired and you'll have access to fast-travel between the Bus Stop, Mines, Town, and Quarry (once that's unlocked).

Answer (score 6):

Complete the Boiler Room bundles at the community centre. The boiler room itself is unlocked by completing two bundles from a previous set- the pantry or craft room bundles are the easiest for this.

Alternatively, if you have a Joja Corp membership, pay 15000g at JojaMart using the Community Development Form.

Answer (score 0):

Complete the bundle in the boiler room at the community centre, and the little guys will fix the carts after you go to sleep.